# problem with implementing a simple work queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having troubles with implementing a simple work queue. Doing some analysis, I am facing a subtle problem. The work queue is backed by a regular linked list. The code looks like this (simplified):

```
0. while (true)  
    1. while (enabled == true)  
        2. acquire lock on the list and get the next action to be executed (blocking operation)  (store it in a local variable)  
        3. execute the action (outside the lock on the list on previous line)
    4. get lock on this work queue  
        5. wait until this work queue has been notified (triggered when setEnabled(true) has been callled)
```

The setEnabled(e) operation looks like this (simplified):

```
enabled = e
if (enabled == true)
    acquire lock on this work queue and do notify()
```

Although this works, there is a condition in which a deadlock occurs. It happens in the following rare situation:

- while an action is being executed during step (3), setEnabled(false) is called
- just before step (4) is entered, setEnabled(true) is called
- now step (5) keeps waiting forever, because this work queue has already been notified but we missed it

How do I solve this? I have been looking at this for some time, but I cannot come up with a solution.

Please note I am fairly new to thread synchronization.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you working with a specific language? .NET languages for example, have most of the work completed for you.

Comment: I am doing this in Java on a mobile device which only supports Java 1.1. I am not only interested in the solution (as I can easily google and download some library), but I would like to find out what I am doing wrong. I never really digged into threads, and I thought this was a good opportunity to improve myself.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the multithreaded memory model is on mobile Java. For Desktop Java I am pretty sure it had some serious bugs all the way up to Java 1.5.

Would be easier to troubleshoot with real Java code over psuedocode.. but I wouldn't be surprised if this was a Java 1.1 bug and not a code bug...

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the problem is a missed notification, then just store another boolean flag, such as "wasNotified". Then at step 5, do a synchronized check of wasNotified. If you were notified, then repeat step 1, otherwise wait for another notification.

You might also look into using a [condition variable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) to implement this (although the Condition class might not be available to you if you are limited to 1.1).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following 2 changes will fix the deadlock bug:

1) change setEnabled as follows:

```
setEnabled(e){
    acquire lock on Q{
        enabled = e 
        if (enabled == true) 
             do Q.notify() 
    }
}
```

2) Add condition to step 5:

if enabled=false, wait until this work queue has been notified (Q.wait())

This approach guarantees that the wait of step 5 will occur only if the enabled flag is currently down.

Comment: I understand the second step. But why did you put the assignment 'enabled = e' into the lock? I cannot find a reason why this is necessary.

Comment: @John: it is not necessary for the deadlock situation, but it synchronizes the access to 'enabled' flag properly. If multiple threads read/write a variable, the accesses should be either synchronized on the same lock, or the variable should be declared as volatile. Otherwise, thread visibility issues may arise.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you check and wait for conditions in a loop, otherwise you may cancel the wait prematurely and that can lead to a deadlock later on:

change this:

```
if ( ! condition )
{
    wait( );
}
```

to this:

```
while ( ! condition )
{
    wait( );
}
```

This comes straight from the documentation for [wait](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I still do not understand why, but I'll do some research to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a worker which can be enabled/disabled which is different from a worker which processes tasks when available. You need to synchronize around the enabled state, not the queue.

```
while (true)  
    synchronize (enabled)
        while (!enabled)
            enabled.wait();
    task = taskList.take();
    task.run();
```

You can reduce the synchronization of enabled (if you are willing to accept visibility problems) by first doing an if(!enabled) check prior to the synchronize block. Basically, the broken paradigm known as double check locking.

Comment: I understand why I have to synchronize on the 'enabled' instead of the 'queue', but is this a big error? Isn't think 'as long as I synchronize on something, it's correct' flawed thinking?

Comment: I think this solution is not completely correct. Say the queue list is empty, and enabled is set to true. This means that the function taskList.take() is blocking. While this thread is waiting, setEnabled(false) is called. Now, once a task is added, the task is executed anyway, as the enabled flag is ignored.

Comment: @John, your implementation in the original post suffers from the same flaw. So I assumed it was acceptable/intended that the worker execute at least one task once enabled. Also, yes, you could sync around anything, but using the queue to sync will mean that enabling/disabling has to wait for add/get operations on your list.